# Rails saving IP address with every create/update request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, ip, env

I'd like to do the following:

define a `before_filter` in `application.rb` that extracts the user's IP address and stores it anywhere, preferably in the session.

define two before filters in all my models as before_create and before_update that add the current user's IP to the object to be stored.

Problem: I cannot access `session[]` neither `env[]` in a model. Can anyone help with a standard solution that I don't know yet?

Regards
Jason

Answer (score 6):

Try this. In your user model add a class attribute accessor

```
cattr_accessor :current_ip
```

In your application controller add:

```
before_filter :set_current_ip

protected
def set_current_ip
    User.current_ip = request.env['REMOTE_ADDR']
end
```

Then in your model you should be able to just call User.current_ip

We do something similar to get the current_user object passed through.

Comment: One note to this is that the REMOTE_ADDR is sometimes a list of IP addresses depending on your setup.

Comment: This solution is a hack that forces instance-specific data into the class.  if you ever wanted to use this concurrenly, you're going to have problems. You're also coupling the models to the controller layer. This makes it harder to do background jobs with your models, as you'll be requiring session data to be present, and when you run with console or Rake, it won't be.  The correct place to audit current user and ip info is at the controller layer, because that's where the requests are coming through. You can use around filters or cachesweepers to do this at the controller layer.

Comment: While I would agree that using `cattr_accessor` in most cases would be a hack, here I believe Lee's approach is logically correct. The User model is a Singleton, supposed to represent the person logging into the site. No matter who that person is, they can only exist in one location. You don't need to attach the value to an instance, because the value will be the same regardless.

Yes, that's a fair amount of assuming, but these are reasonable and very common assumptions for this particular scenario. Every rule has an exception, as they say.

Answer upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

You're having trouble doing what you want because Rails is *designed* not to allow you to have access to session information in your models. It's the classic separation of concerns with MVC. Models are meant to work independently of your other layers, and you'll be thankful they do when you start doing things with Rake or other system tasks where you won't have a session.

The

```
cattr_accessor :current_ip
```

is a horrible approach. It's a hack and it should be apparent why. Yes, it may work, but it's the wrong approach to this problem.

Since you're tracking "who" did "what" by their IP, the logical place for this to happen is in the controller layer. There are several approaches you can take, including using CacheSweepers as auditors, as outlined in the Rails Recipes book. CacheSweepers can observe models but also have access to all controller information.  Using the ditry attributes in a rails model, you can see exactly what changed.

```
@user  = User.find_by_login "bphogan"
@user.login = "Brian"
@user.save
@user.changed
=> ["login"]
@user.changes
=> {"login"=>["bphogan", "brian"]}
@user.login_was
=> "bphogan"
```

Combine this with the session info you have and you have a pretty awesome auditor.

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the IP in the session, you can create a before filter in the applicationController. Like this, for each action, the filter is called and the ip is stored.

Comment: Hi Kiva, 

this is exactly what I tried to to as mentioned above. Problem: I can store the IP in the session, but I cannot access the session in my models!

Comment: I don't understand why you need to save the ip for each create/update object. You can't access to the session object in the model because this object is only accessible in controllers.

Comment: We provide a system for a customers who'se coworkers can change content. If a misconfiguration occures, we need to know, who made the mistake. And due to several reasons we cannot rely on the login data aof a user but on the IP. I know, that I cannot access the env or session in a model. Thats what I wrote in my initial question. So the question was: Is there a common receipe to store the users IP with every create/update of any model?

Answer (score 0):

[authlogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic) is a plugin to manage users login/sessions etc, it has a built in option to track the users IP

Comment: Hi amikazmi, 

authorization itself is not the problem at all. I will have a look at the plugin either way. What I want to do, is, to store the users IP with every requests that creates or updates an object in my DB. Problem: I cannot access the session or env in my model in a before filter.

Comment: if you need to save the IP in your user table, that plugin will do that for you, if you need to save the IP in each of your models that got created updated, kiva answer is the right way.

Comment: Hi Again, 

I'm quite unsure what you mean. What kiva wrote, is exactly what I planned. I can store the IP in the session using a before_filter in my application controller. Ok. But when I want to store the IP with every create/update of an object, I need to create before_create and before_update filters in my model. So far. My problem is, that I cannot access the session in my model. And kiva's answer does not address this at all.

Answer (score 0):

What you really need is a versioning plugin - I suggest having a look at one of the fine solutions at http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/activerecord_versioning.html

Edit: archived version of that link (was 404 since sometime in 2012): https://web.archive.org/web/20111004161536/http://ruby-toolbox.com:80/categories/activerecord_versioning.html

Comment: Link's dead. :(

Comment: @JoshuaPinter it's been a full seven years since my original comment, but I've added a link to the page on archive.org for easy reference in the future :)